# How to impersonate a GCP service account from credentials generated by Application Default Credentials

Tags: google-cloud-platform, service-accounts

I have a service account and I am granting 'ServiceAccountUser' role on this service account to one of the real user. The user has Application Default Credentials set as part of his configuration to avoid login screen on every run. I am not sure what is the best way for this user to run a code that manipulates certain resources accessible only to the service account. I do not want to use Service Account Key JSON file for security reasons. I am trying following code

```
import google.auth
service_account_email='my-service-account@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com'
adc_credentials,adc_project=google.auth.default()

delegated_credentials=adc_credentials.with_subject(service_account_email)
```

I am getting error:
AttributeError: 'Credentials' object has no attribute 'with_subject'

Comment: You need to import `google.oauth2` to use `with_subject`.

Comment: Add more details to your question on which type of credentials are being discovered by ADC (user credentials, service account). Impersonation is used by Domain Wide Delegation so that a service account can impersonate a user.

Comment: @JohnHanley : Thanks for your suggestions. I want to impersonate a service account from a user credentials not the other way around. My resources are granted access to service accounts not to individual users.

Comment: You cannot impersonate a service account with user credentials. Only the reverse use case is supported.

Comment: to be clear You have a service account with certain access to resources, a user account without that acces, but with the role of ServiceAccountUser. And you want this user to be impersonated as if it is the service account to have access to the restricted resources, all of this without using the Service Account Key JSON?

Comment: @JoséSoní - Thats true. Currently we use SA Key JSON files but that goes out of hands quickly and security issue so we want to switch to impersonation approach

Answer (score 0):

As specified [Here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts#the_service_account_user_role) Service Account User Role grants you the permission to deploy resourrces with the service account, not the permission of becvoming this account.

If the concern is that the credentials when they are long term are easily compromised then you can use [Short lived credentials](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts#short-lived_service_account_credentials)

For impersonating a service Account you need the role of Service account token creator. [here](https://medium.com/@tanujbolisetty/gcp-impersonate-service-accounts-36eaa247f87c) is an article that explaines this impersonation process.